# Should I declare function prototype for every function?

Tags: objective-c, ios, function

In Obj-C, what's the best practice for function prototype ? Should I include them for every function in my class or just the one that's needed (i.e a function call happens before a function implementation)

Comment: Can you explain more? Are you talking about methods exposed in a public header vs private ones? Or forward declarations for other things?

Comment: I meant the private interface. Forward declaration for private methods.

Comment: Is there something else you're looking for? If these answers work you should accept one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, there is no need to forward declare private functions and methods unless the compiler requires it. I can think of no practical benefit to forward declaring proactively. Even for internal documentation purposes, it is better to put the documentation close to the function rather than all at the top of the file.

Of course you have to declare public methods and functions in the header, and you should document them there as well. But that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 3):

*Best* practice is to have exactly one prototype for every function and method you define. Where that prototype should be depends on whether you want to expose the function to the world outside of your class. If you skip a prototype and just include the function body, you'll probably get away with it. (e.g. you could in the example below send your controller a `stop` from outside the class at runtime.) But it's best to make sure you dot your i's and cross your t's. Notice in my example below that everything is accounted for. Hopefully this helps.

MyAppController.h:

```
@interface MyAppController : NSObject {
   id thing;
@private
   id noneOfYourBeeswax;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) id thing;

-(id)initWithThing:(id)thing;
-(void)start;

@end
```

MyAppController.m:

```
@interface MyAppController () // anonymous category

@property (readwrite, retain) id thing;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSThread *noneOfYourBeeswax;

-(void)start_internal;
-(void)stop;

@end


@implementation MyAppController 

@synthesize thing;
@synthesize noneOfYourBeeswax;

-(id)initWithThing:(id)thing_ {
   if ((self = [super init]) != nil) {
      self.thing = thing_;
   }

   return self;
}


-(void)start {
   // I think I'm doing this wrong but you get the picture
   self.noneOfYourBeeswax = [[[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:start_internal object:nil] autorelease];
}

// The real worker
-(void)start_internal {
   while (such and such) {
      // do something useful
   }

   [self stop];
}


-(void)stop {
   // clean up
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

If your source file is quite large, it could be useful (and polite) to document the internal ones all at the top:

```
@interface MyClass ()
- (void)internalMethod;
...
@end
```

But there's no need to unless they have circular references. (A calls B, B calls A, can't put both first).  I've been known to move one higher in the file to obviate the need for a private interface.